# How can I capture the HttpContext.Response.Headers for all web api responses?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to capture all response headers for all responses in a Web API, but the HttpContext.Response.Headers collection is always empty. I'm currently running .NET Core and ASP.Net Core 3.1.

Implementation starts with the Startup.cs where middleware is added.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
  
    app.UseMiddleware<CaptureResponseHeaders>();
   
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

}
```

Next the middleware class

```
public class CaptureResponseHeaders
{
    public CaptureResponseHeaders(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
     
        if(httpContext.Response.Headers.Count > 0) //this is always zero.
```

And the request, a simple Get API endpoint

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
   
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    
    var rng = new Random();
    
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
   
}
```

And the response headers I expect to capture

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 18:47:43 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

Comment: While the answer from Peter Rasmussen sounds good, it looks to me like all you need to do I make sure your middleware is added to the pipeline first so that it's last in the response unwrap and use `await _next()` before any of your logic in `Invoke(...)` to get the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in your invoke method:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(state => {
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;

        if (httpContext.Response.Headers.Count > 0)
            CaptureHeaders(); //TODO your implementation

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, context);

    await _next(context);
}
```

This lets you capture the Response right before it is sent to the client. You can also use OnCompleted to get the Response after it is sent.

An image of the headers can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: 'Content-Length' header is never there for me, I guess this is because the response is streamed so not available at this point ... any ideas how to get it without reading the stream?

Comment: Peter, this is not related to this question but I didn't find email address on your page. I'm referring to [your blog](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2022/05/08/csharp-how-to-set-baseaddress-on-httpclient/) and I just want to state that it is ducked up! Not your blog. The slash thing! Who in the right set of mind and no malicious intent would implement such a gotcha? I want my three hours back... On a more serious note - do you have any idea what the purpose of that "feature" is?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that if you move the addition of your middleware up the stack, it will be executed early for the request and late for the response.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    // here 
    app.UseMiddleware<CaptureResponseHeaders>();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

}
```

As for the zero you keep seeing, try to put your capture logic after the execution of the rest of the pipeline.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await _next();

        if(httpContext.Response.Headers.Count > 0) 
        {
            // do responsive things
        }
    }
```